# Make service observable wait until receives response from other observable - angular 9

Tags: observable, angular-promise, angular-services, angular9, emit

I have a parent-child component scenario. On button click in parent component, I am calling below function:

```
public goNextStep() {
   this.fetchAttributes.emit(new FetchAttributesEvent("myComponent", param));//calls api and get data
    this._stateService.updateStep(2); // just update step number and go to next
  }
```

In child component, I have observable implementation for both of these as below:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit{

    attributes: any[];
    ngOnInit() {
           this._stateService.attributesDataInjector$
           .subscribe(
           attributesData => {

          if (attributesData != null) {
            //live data
            this.attributes = JSON.parse(attributesData);
          }
        }
      )

      this._stateService.stepUpdator$
      .subscribe(
        newStep => {
       // Use this.attributes value;
       }
     )
   }
}
```

Now my problem is that since emit() calls external service and get data, it takes time, whereas update step is just local operation so it happens quickly. So stepUpdator$ operation completes first and try to use this.attributes which is empty at this time as api call is still in process. As a result, I get error of undefied here and processing moves on. Later, service call completes and attributesDataInjector$ initializes this.attributes.

I want to somehow wait until this.attributes is initialized by attributesDataInjector$ and then process stepUpdator$ (Something like promise) but I am unable to do that. Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `skipUntil` `rxjs` operator to achieve that functionality. It works upon two observables & prevents the values from first observable until the second one emits the value. For more information, you can read [this](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/skipUntil).

For your scenario:

```js
import { skipUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

this._stateService.stepUpdator$
  .pipe(skipUntil(this._stateService.attributesDataInjector$))
  .subscribe(newStep => {})
```